# How do i make a list a list of list?

Tags: python

How do I get the items from the "list" shown below to look like the "new_list" which has the same amount of items in each list

```
list  = [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,          new_list = [[1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
         0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,                      [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
         1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,                      [1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
         0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]              `       [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket somewhere in `new_list` -- also, whats your logic for making sublists? maybe sublists are 8 elements?  Or split the list evenly into 4 sublists?  (And in that case, what if len(list) doesn't divide evenly by 4?)

Comment: Shouldn't we have waited for an answer to jedwards' question before closing this as dupe ... ?

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to finding consecutive numbers(1,1,1) in each list from multiple angles. e.g vertically, horizontally, and diagonally. I found making the list into sublists easier for me to do that. I am open to other ways if you are willing to show me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `slicing` :

```
>>> l= [1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,          
...     0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,                      
...     1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,                      
...     0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1] 

>>> [l[i:i+8] for i in range(0,len(l),8)]
[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

for check the consecutive 1 in your sub-lists :

```
>>> new=[l[i:i+8] for i in range(0,len(l),8)]
>>> [all(i==1 for i in sub) for sub in new]
[False, False, False, False]
>>> new.append([1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
>>> [all(i==1 for i in sub) for sub in new]
[False, False, False, False, True]
```

Comment: If i may ask one more question :). how do I check each item in the new list to see if there are consecutive number of 1's( 1,1,1,) and not (1,0,1)?

Comment: @MrAutodidact You can use the `all` function ,checkout the edit! and accept the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks once again for your help and expedient replies